Is it possible to use a Python package/module that is not installed in QGIS in a Plugin?
I want to use a Python package, EPANETTOOLS, which is a python package that allows hydraulic simulation from Epanet (INP) files, in a plugin that I am developing for QGIS, but this is not a module initially installed in QGIS Python. My question is whether I can actually use it, as this plugin will be shared with other users.

Yes you can, other plugin developers do this. You'll either need to provide your users with a list of additional libraries that need to be installed (and possibly installation instructions for less tech savvy users) or you need to include a copy of the libraries with your plugin.
